# Using Thin Web Server with HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, https

I'm using the Thin web server to serve my Rails app.

- Starting the server with `thin start` serves `http` requests.
- Starting the server with `thin start --ssl` serves `https` requests.

**Is there a way to have `thin` serve both `http` and `https` requests concurrently?**

The reason I ask is because when I use `redirect_to some_path` in my controllers, they redirect to `http`. Since `thin` is serving `https` requests, nothing is rendered.

Note: I'm using `Rack::SSL` in `Rails 3.0.7`.

Comment: Simplest option is probably to run two separate instances of thin: one accepting SSL requests and one accepting plaintext requests. Any reason you don't want to do this?

(Alternatively, if thin is running behind another web server, like Apache or Nginx, you only need one instance of thin: the frontend server can report whether the request came in over SSL.)

Comment: You can't run two instances of `thin` on the same port.

Comment: You can't accept both HTTP and HTTPS connections on the same port, either. (This is why, by default convention, HTTP runs on port 80 whereas HTTPS runs on port 443.)

Comment: Ah, you're right! I was confused because ports 80 and 443 are hidden since they're the default. Perhaps I need to figure out how to force `redirect_to` to push users to `https` instead. If you want to convert your comment above into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I have HTTP running on port 3000 and HTTPS running on port 3001. How would you create a "smart redirect" policy for your development environment such that redirects from HTTP to HTTPS also changes the port from 3000 to 3001? Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Comment converted to answer as requested.)

Simplest option is probably to run two separate instances of thin: one accepting SSL requests and one accepting plaintext requests. Any reason you don't want to do this? (Alternatively, if thin is running behind another web server, like Apache or Nginx, you only need one instance of thin: the frontend server can report whether the request came in over SSL.)

You can't accept both HTTP and HTTPS connections on the same port. (This is why, by default convention, HTTP runs on port 80 whereas HTTPS runs on port 443.)

Answer (score 4):

you can use foreman (https://github.com/ddollar/foreman);

You create a Procfile with 2 process then start both with `forman start` command.

put this on a file called `Procfile`:

```
web: thin start
ssl: thin start --ssl
```

Then use `foreman start` and he start the 2 process.
This is how i am using... hope this helps you!

Comment: How does this work since you cannot have 2 instances of thin running on the same port? And even if you start the ssl instance on another port, say `thin start --ssl -p 3001`, how do you intelligently handle redirects from http to https within your application?

Comment: @JZ11 Nginx will intelligently handle redirects/forwards depending on protocol. But I'd also like to know the workaround.