# Rails app using Thin and SSL on Heroku (Procfile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, thin, procfile

I have been having some issues with running a Rails app using the Thin web server over SSL on Heroku. One thing that I think may be causing my issues is that I am not starting the thin server using ssl (such as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559731/using-thin-web-server-with-http-and-https) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589636/enable-https-in-a-rails-app-on-a-thin-server)). However, I do not know the correct syntax to boot a thin server using ssl on Heroku. Here are the different procfile variations I have tried with no luck:

`web: thin start --ssl -p $PORT`

`web: bundle exec thin start --ssl -p $PORT`

`web: bundle exec rails s thin --ssl -p $PORT`

`web: thin start --ssl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Heroku, SSL is terminated before requests hit your app. You app will only see normal HTTP traffic. I don't think you will need to pass any parameters to `thin`, just start it as normal, and you should be able to access your site over HTTPS using https://example.herokuapp.com/.

If you have a custom domain, there's more info in this [Dev Center article on SSL endpoints](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint).